# Google Cloud Platform: Unable to upload a new file version in Storage via API

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wrote a script that uploads a file to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage:

Ref: ***https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert***

```
function submitForm(bucket, accessToken) {

    console.log("Fetching the file...");
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var name = input.files[0].name;
    var uploadUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'+
     bucket + '/o?uploadType=media&access_token=' + accessToken + '&name=' + name;
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(uploadUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: input.files[0]
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            location.reload();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('Got error:', err);
        });

}
```

It works perfectly fine when uploading a new file.
However, I get a 403 status code in the API response body while trying to replace an existing file with a new version.

Please note that:

- The OAuth 2.0 scope for Google Cloud Storage is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`
- I did enable the versioning for the destination bucket

Could someone help me in pointing out what I did wrong?

**Update I:**

As suggested, I am trying to invoke the rewrite function as follows:

```
    const input = document.getElementsByName('uploadFile')[0];
    const name = input.files[0].name;


 const overwriteObjectUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/' + 
     'b/' + bucket +
     '/o/' + name +
     '/rewriteTo/b/' + bucket +
     '/o/' + name;

    fetch(overwriteObjectUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: input.files[0]
    })
```

However, I am getting a 400 (bad request error).

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Parse Error"}],"code":400,"message":"Parse Error"}}
```

Could you explain me what I am doing wrong?

**Update II:**

By changing `body: input.files[0]` with `body: input.files[0].data` I made it working... Theoretically!

I get a positive response body:

```
{  
   "kind":"storage#rewriteResponse",
   "totalBytesRewritten":"43",
   "objectSize":"43",
   "done":true,
   "resource":{  
      "kind":"storage#object",
      "id":"mybuck/README.txt/1520085847067373",
      "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/mybuck/o/README.txt",
      "name":"README.txt",
      "bucket":"mybuck",
      "generation":"1520085847067373",
      "metageneration":"1",
      "contentType":"text/plain",
      "timeCreated":"2018-03-03T14:04:07.066Z",
      "updated":"2018-03-03T14:04:07.066Z",
      "storageClass":"MULTI_REGIONAL",
      "timeStorageClassUpdated":"2018-03-03T14:04:07.066Z",
      "size":"43",
      "md5Hash":"UCQnjcpiPBEzdl/iWO2e1w==",
      "mediaLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/mybuck/o/README.txt?generation=1520085847067373&alt=media",
      "crc32c":"y4PZOw==",
      "etag":"CO2VxYep0NkCEAE="
   }
}
```

Whit as well a new generation number (versioning enabled).
However, the file content has been not updated: I did append new strings but they did not show off within the file. Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How did you enable versioning for the destination bucket? It looks "Object Versioning cannot currently be controlled using the Google Cloud Platform Console." -> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning

Comment: @JL-HN I just did run `gsutil versioning set on gs://[BUCKET_NAME]` within the GCP online console. Is the upload process correct or am I not able to replace an existing file because of missing metadata info?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information available it's difficult to diagnose this issue with certainty- however I would check the roles assigned to the user or service account you are using for this operation.

As you have been able to upload a file, but not overwrite a file, this sounds like you may have assigned the user or service account that is attempting to perform this task the 'Storage Object Creator' role.

Users/service accounts with the Storage Object Creator role can create new objects in buckets but not overwrite existing ones (you can see this mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)).

If this is the case, you could try assigning the user/service account the role of 'Storage Object Admin' which allows users full control over bucket objects.

Comment: I am performing this operation using the project owner account. I did attach to the first post the error response body: it looks like a parsing issue.

Answer (score 1):

"insert" is only to be used to create new objects per the [Methods](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#methods) section of the API's documentation, so you'll need to use "[rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite)" to rewrite an existing object.

Comment: Hi, I just did update my question. Could you please give a look at? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the response body?

Comment: I did attach to the first post the error response body: it looks like a parsing issue.